# Any way to get Automation unstuck?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation that is just stuck; sometimes after 10,000 run's I'll see one or two get stuck. This particular one is stuck on a Data Extract Activity. It's run 20,000+ time successfully before and nothing changed. The DE has data in it as well.

I couldn't find any details on this issue. It's been running for 16 hours now when a successful run or failure will usually average 3-4 minutes. Hovering over the activity in question just says that status is `RUNNING`.

1. Will this ever pass or fail?
2. Is there any way to get alert/notification if an automation is running longer than 10 minutes?
3. Any insight into why this got stuck?
4. Any way to get additional logging?

[image: Stuck Automation]

Comment: SF support can provide details.

Comment: @Jordan, have you communicated this issue to SF Support? If yes, what was the issue?

Comment: @Niko They can get you server log but it doesn't help with anything after the fact since it's a server timeout issue on their side. Basically just re-run it after it causes a mess (time out is 48 hours) because they don't care enough to implement re-try or proper logging on UI.